# Typescript error Type '{ Count: number; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ Count: number; }]'

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing unit tests for a react component. To mock the data I created a JSON object and imported it to the unit test file. The expected data has a property of type

```
  Options: [
    {
      Count: number;
    },
  ];
```

and the JSON object I am passing has a property like

```
  "Options":[ 
    {"Count": 50}
  ],
```

I am sending an array of objects like I am supposed to but it is showing the above error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way to define object array type

```
Options:{ Count: number; }[]
```